# Run Ansible task only on one server - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I have my ansible task running in all my api_servers which i would restrict it to run only on one IP (one of the api_server)
I have added run_once: true but it didnt helps.

Kindly advise.
EDIT :

Will the below work?  I have 10 instances of app_servers running, I want the task to run only on one app_server

```
run_once: true
when:
    - inventory_hostname == groups['app_servers'][0]
```

Where my inventory file is like

```
[app_servers]
prod_app_[1:4]
```

Comment: is `--limit` an option ? so you will run the playbook against the specific server

Comment: Your below should work. But you don't need both (run_once and when). I've added a complete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write my playbook like that:

```
 ---
 # Run on all api_servers
 - hosts: api_servers
   tasks:
   - name: do something on all api_servers
     #...

 # Run only on one api_server e.q. api_server_01
 - hosts: api_server_01
   tasks:
   - name: Gather data from api_server_01 
     #...
```

The other option would be to work with `when:` or to run the playbook with the `--limit` option

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: do something only when on api_server_01
    #...
    when: inventory_hostname == "api_server_01"
```

EDIT:
Here you will see all the option in one example:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="run_once"
    run_once: true
  - debug: msg=all
  - debug: msg="run on the first of the group"
    when: inventory_hostname == groups['app_servers'][0]

# Option with separated hosts, this one will be faster if gather_facts is not tuned.
- hosts: app_servers[0]
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="run on the first of the group"
```

Comment: Will the below work? @CLNRMN . I have 10 instances of app_servers running, I want the task to run only on one app_server
run_once: true
when:
    - inventory_hostname == groups['app_servers'][0]
Where my inventory file is like    
[app_servers]
prod_app_[1:4]

Answer (score 0):

(Since I can not comment, I have to answer.)

What about `delegate_to`? Where you delegate the task to a specific host.

```yaml
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Install vim on specific host 
      package:
        name: vim
        state: present
      delegate_to: staging_machine
```

Or

As @user2599522 mentioned: `--limit` is also an option to use:

> You can also limit the hosts you target on a particular run with the --limit flag. ([Patterns and ansible-playbook flags)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#patterns-and-ansible-playbook-flags)